# Show "Does it affect?" with hypothesis test

Tags: anova, t-test

I am trying to learn ttest and ANOVA for my project. I need to know that my subjects answers "effected" by the feedback they get from the first question.
What should I use to show "sth did effect or not sth"? 
ANOVA or ttest?

Thanks in advance.

My data is:

A person answers a question and receives a feedback as "good/bad" than he/she answers another question. Does the second answer effected by the feedback or not? That is what i want to learn.

Comment: Can you describe the data more clearly? ANOVA is a generalization of a two-sample t-test for more than two groups, so it is a matter of any of the two only if you want to compare the means of two or more groups (or means of a metric variable for two or more levels levels of a categorical variable). But a t-test can also be used with a single sample or a paired sample, so we need more info what it is you actually want to check and how your problem looks like.

Comment: If these are experimental data with randomly assigned conditions, I would be comfortable with using (causal) language like "X affects Y". But if these are data from surveys, you should really use more associative language.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the second answer, does the answer of the person get measured in a metric sense? E.g., is it response time or a freely assigned number of performance (say 0 to 100) or something like that, or are you recording if the person gets it correct/wrong the second time. And would you like to say something about each individual person or about all persons "on average"?

Comment: "*sth*"? Please expand your abbreviations. You don't have a 140-character limit. Please also be consistent with use of affect/effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ANOVA comparing 2 groups is exactly equal to a 2-sample pooled t-test with 2-tailed alternative.  So it may not matter which you use.

Some advantages to using the t-test: you can do a 1-tailed test, you can do an approximation if you believe that the variances of the 2 groups differ.  A confidence interval is more straight forward (automatic in some software).

Some advantages to using ANOVA: can compare more than 2 groups.